# Github require status checks to complete before merging

Tags: github

I know how to require status checks to pass before merging, but I am looking to just require them to complete, regardless if they pass or not.

Specifically, we have a unit test check that runs on every pull request. We do not want to block merging if they fail, but we want the developer to be required to see the results before merging the branch. Right now they can merge it in the middle of running unit tests.

Do you know any way to do this? I have reviewed the github documentation and can't find anything other than the standard branch protection rules, which does not have this option. Thank you for your help!

P.S. There was a similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59878097/github-requiring-status-checks-to-be-reviewed), but it was never answered and the poster never clarified.

Comment: Where do those status checks run? If they send build status to GitHub you *can* use the branch protection rules: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/administering-a-repository/enabling-required-status-checks

Comment: The checks are run on a separate build server running Jenkins, triggered by a webhook from github. My understanding is the branch protection rule option that is specified in that link blocks the merge if the status check fails, which we don't want to do. I guess we could have Jenkins always send over the "passed" status, but that defeats the purpose because we won't be able to see if the unit tests actually passed or not.

Comment: *"Right now they can merge it in the middle of running unit tests"* - but why would they do this? *Are* people doing that? Have you tried *talking to them* about it? It sounds like you're trying to solve a people problem, and more GitHub rules isn't the way to do that.

Comment: That is a fair point. We have multiple large teams working in the same repository, and it would just be easiest to enforce it through GitHub rules. Thank you for helping!

Comment: "It sounds like you're trying to solve a people problem". Pretty sure GitHub PRs help to solve people problems - otherwise there wouldn't be much "require" anything in the branch configuration policy. Wouldn't be much good without it.